# Can I use windows 8 Mail to sync Gmail tabs?

Tags: windows-8.1, gmail

I really, really like the Google tabs.  I would love to have this feature working properly in the Windows 8 Mail application.  The tabs for Primary, Updates, Social, Promotions and Forums are great.

However, as it is now, Mail is simply just taking everything and lumping it together.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your mail is stored server-side and is not categorized like Gmail has it. Gmail pulls it down, then sorts it all nice for you, client-side. That's where the buck stops.